# Exception occured: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter

Hello I am learning flutter and am getting a json from an api but when decoding it in my model I am getting the error listed below. I know it has to do with my pagination as the location result is fine, but cant figure out what I need to do to fix the pagination result. I tried a bunch of tutorials but am having no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

**Error**

```
Exception occured: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast*
```

**location.dart**

```
class Locations {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String street;
  final String city;
  final String state;

  Locations(
    {
      this.id,
      this.name,
      this.street,
      this.city,
      this.state,
    }
  );

  Locations.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : id = json['id'],
      name = json['name'],
      street = json['street'],
      city = json['city'],
      state = json['state'];
}

class Pagination {
  final int pages;
  final int totalResults;

  Pagination(this.pages, this.totalResults);

  Pagination.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : pages = json['pages'],
      totalResults = json['count'];
}

class LocationsResponse {
  final List<Locations> results;
  final List<Pagination> pagination;
  final String error;

  LocationsResponse(this.results, this.pagination, this.error);

  LocationsResponse.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : results = (json["results"] as List).map((i) => new Locations.fromJSON(i)).toList(),
      pagination = (json['pagination'] as List).map((i) => new Pagination.fromJSON(i)).toList(),
      error = "";

  LocationsResponse.withError(String errorValue)
      : results = List(),
        pagination = List(),
        error = errorValue;
}
```

**Example Return**

```
{  
   results:[  
      {  
         id:1,
         name:House,
         street:1234 This Street,
         city:Example City,
         state:Ca      
      }
   ],
   pagination:{  
      count:1,
      pages:0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pagination` is `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.
 change code like this:

```
 LocationsResponse.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    : results = (json["results"] as List).map((i) => new Locations.fromJSON(i)).toList(),
      pagination = Pagination.fromJSON(json['pagination']),
      error = "";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, When I do that I get the error the initializer Pagination cannot be assigned to the field type List<Pagination>

Comment: I got it. I chaged final List<Pagination> pagination; to just final pagination and all seems to be working well! thank you